# Android layout-swXXdp for galaxy SII

Tags: android

i have a rather simple question, but i did not find any correct answer, 
my question is: what SW(smallest width) do i use to control the SG SII, i thought it was 219, 220, 240, but none of these worked,
thank you for your time

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030789/smallest-width-for-galaxy-s-and-galaxy-s2

Try 218.

Comment: I have tried the 320dp, works good, but then again, the GSIII, that worked already with the  306dp, took also the 320dp folder

Comment: Why are you creating separate layouts for phone screen sizes? Generally, the sw layouts are used for tablets.

Comment: i have a standard image, can't create one for each density because i have like 200 images, for the S2 it looks a little too big, for the S3 looks a little too small, so i think i need to separate the dimens for each one

Comment: Got it. Yeah, you will have to go about it this way then :(